# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct

Tags: c#

Queston is answered thanks for the help :)

I made a code with multiple methods in a class but when I try to run it it says

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

on the two methods that are not the main methods. I read around and found that someone had the same problem and the case was that the methods weren’t in the class. But couldn't figure out how to fix that. Any tips?

PS: I’m pretty new to coding ;)

```
using System;

namespace Testing
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args )
        {
            string answer;

            Console.WriteLine ("Would you like to divide or multiply? Type your choice.");

            Start:
            answer = (Console.ReadLine ());

            if (answer == "multiply") 
            {
                MultiplyingMethod;
            }
            {
                else if (answer == "divide")
                {
                    DividingMethod;
                }  
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Please type multiply or divide.");

                goto Start;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DividingMethod ()
    {           
        double num01;
        double num02;

        Console.Write ("Enter a number to be divided");
        num01 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        Console.Write ("Enter a number to divide by");
        num02 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        Console.WriteLine (num01 + " divided by " + num02 + " is equal to " + num01 / num02);

        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
    public static void MultiplyingMethod ()
    {
        double num01;
        double num02;

        Console.Write ("Enter a number to be multiplied");
        num01 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        Console.Write ("Enter a numeber to multiply by");
        num02 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        Console.WriteLine (num01 + " multiplied by " + num02 + " equals " + num01 * num02);

        Console.WriteLine ("");
        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: seems like you need check parenthesis

Comment: Here:     goto Start;
            }
        }
    }
public static void DividingMethod ()

Comment: also please fix the formatting

Comment: Sorry but this code has too many problems to begin with. Please start with a really basic coding tutorial.

Comment: @RvdK it's not that bad really - there are far blacker sins out here on this site

Comment: Calling functions needs to be with parenthesis: MultiplyingMethod(); . Also please try not to use goto's, it may sound easy but it will only complicate  your code.

Comment: @RvdK yeah I had learned that goto wasn't the best, just haven't looked up the proper way yet ;) And thx for the help

Comment: @Thusten Try not to use "Goto" in programming, really not a good practice, try to use while loop instead hint: while(isValidInput == false)

Answer (score 1):

Working version:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string answer;

    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to divide or multiply? Type your choice.");

    while (true)
    {
        answer = (Console.ReadLine());

        if (answer == "multiply")
        {
            MultiplyingMethod();
            break;
        }
        else if (answer == "divide")
        {
            DividingMethod();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please type multiply or divide.");
        }
    }
}

public static void DividingMethod()
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number to be divided");
    double num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter a number to divide by");
    double num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(num01 + " divided by " + num02 + " is equal to " + num01/num02);

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void MultiplyingMethod()
{
    double num01;
    double num02;

    Console.Write("Enter a number to be multiplied");
    num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter a numeber to multiply by");
    num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(num01 + " multiplied by " + num02 + " equals " + num01*num02);

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

- Call a method with no parameters like `MultiplyingMethod();` instead of `MultiplyingMethod;`. Thats no valid C#
- Please don't use `goto`. It makes your code messy. Take a look at [loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e10e56%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should call the methods with ().

Write MultiplyingMethod(); instead of MultiplyingMethod(); and
DividingMethod(); instead of DividingMethod;

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string answer;

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to divide or multiply? Type your choice.");

        Start:
            answer = (Console.ReadLine());

            if (answer == "multiply")
            {
                MultiplyingMethod();
            }
            else if (answer == "divide")
            {
                DividingMethod();
            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please type multiply or divide.");

                goto Start;
            }

        }
        public static void DividingMethod()
        {
            double num01;
            double num02;

            Console.Write("Enter a number to be divided");
            num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter a number to divide by");
            num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(num01 + " divided by " + num02 + " is equal to " + num01 / num02);

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        public static void MultiplyingMethod()
        {
            double num01;
            double num02;

            Console.Write("Enter a number to be multiplied");
            num01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter a numeber to multiply by");
            num02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(num01 + " multiplied by " + num02 + " equals " + num01 * num02);

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

In addition, never use goto, it is not good!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code:

- Calling functions should be done with the syntax: funcname(params). So `DividingMethod;` becomes `DividingMethod();`
- Try not to use goto (it sounds easy but makes your code really hard to read and debug)
- Too many brackets

> if (answer == "multiply") 
>       {
>         MultiplyingMethod;
>       }
>       {
>       else if (answer == "divide")
>       {
>         DividingMethod;
>       }
>       }

Should be:

```
if (answer == "multiply") 
{
    MultiplyingMethod();
}
else if (answer == "divide")
{
    DividingMethod();
}
```